# Logic Behind IQR Outlier Detection

Tags: data-cleaning

Why we using IQR to detect outlier in Dataset , what is the logic behind the method and is there any other method to detect outliers?

Answer (score 1):

IQR says observations in a feature that are "too far" from the median are outliers.

There are many many algorithms to find "outliers". Here are a few - [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search?q=outlier) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=outlier).

However finding outliers is contextual. For a given problem, what is an outlier may be defined differently. The definition needs to be in the context of the problem and the data.

Next, what do you do with the outlier is a harder question. Again, this is contextual to the problem being solved. Some replace the outlier with something "closer" to the expected normal values. Some delete the observation. Some may set an indicator value. Or more...

Then is this a univariate or multivariate outlier? The feature itself may have few outliers, based on the definition. But when looked in context of the observation, the value may be an outlier.  For example, take AGE and INCOME in a dataset. If AGE == 1 years old, I would not expect an INCOME of \$50,000. Though an INCOME of \$50,000 might not be an outlier in the context of all INCOMEs, in the context of AGE and INCOME, \$50,000 might be an outlier. Then what is done about it is back to the context of the problem.